# Как вывести содержимое тегов XML и их атрибуты в php?

Tags: php, xml

Есть xml файл, у него есть теги с содержимым, типа такого

```
<thistag>Text</thistag>
```

и есть теги у которых есть только атрибуты, типа таких

```
<thistag type="1" name="Vasya"/>
```

Так же есть вложенные теги. Так же теги не уникальны.
Как вывести содержимое всех тегов и их атрибутов, включая дочерние теги, именно в таком порядке в каком они находятся в xml с помощью php?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/simplexml.examples-basic.php - это средство работы с XML. Все данные будут считываться (обрабатываться) в соответствии с файлом. То есть какой порядок тегов в файле, таким и будет способ обхода

Comment: @WilpKron ну это нужно для каждого элемента свой путь прописывать, а как их вывести не прописывая пути?

Comment: ```$movies = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr); print_r($movies);``` <br> или же посмотрите как обход объектов происходит

Comment: @WilpKron там в примере xml напрямую в переменную записан, а как записать его из файла чтобы всё работало? include? simplexml_load_file? и в примере по ссылке получают только часть содержимого, и или атрибуты либо содержимое тега, как сделать так чтобы вывелись сразу и атрибуты и элементы?
Я ламер в php.